# Amazon RDS node In AWS Explorer (AWS Toolkit for Eclipse) Does not show DB instances

Tags: amazon-web-services

when I click to Amazon RDS node I don't see any DB, even I have 2 instances up and running.
The Access Key ID I am using to connec to AWS belongs to a user that belongs to a group with these policies:

Group Policies:

- AdministratorAccess
- AmazonRDSFullAccess
- AmazonEC2FullAccess

Comment: Are you sure you're looking in the correct region?

Comment: It was this. Please convert to answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the region you are looking at to the same region your RDS instances reside in.